# smooth image menu with pure CSS

Tags: html, css

im trying to achieve this: [image](http://i62.tinypic.com/2885r4n.png) | [demo](http://www.alohatechsupport.net/examples/image-menu-1.html)

with just pure css. how am i supposed to achieve this?

this is the div tag for the page of the demo:

```
<div class="jimgMenu">
  <ul>
    <li id="landscapes"><a href="#">Landscapes</a></li>
    <li id="people"><a href="#">People</a></li>
    <li id="nature"><a href="#">Nature</a></li>
    <li id="abstract"><a href="#">Abstract</a></li>
    <li id="urban"><a href="#">Urban</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**edit: here is the css(stackoverflow says it looks like your question is most code add more details):**

```
.jimgMenu {
    position: relative;
    width: 670px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 25px 0px 0px;
}
.jimgMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1340px;
}
.jimgMenu ul li {
    float: left;
}
.jimgMenu ul li a {
    text-indent: -1000px;
    background: #FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0%;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 78px;
    height: 200px;
}
.jimgMenu ul li.landscapes a {
    background: url(images/landscapes.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
}
.jimgMenu ul li.people a {
    background: url(images/people.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
}
.jimgMenu ul li.nature a {
    background: url(images/nature.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
}
.jimgMenu ul li.abstract a {
    background: url(images/abstract.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
}
.jimgMenu ul li.urban a {
    background: url(images/urban.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
    min-width: 310px;
}
```

Comment: Where's you jimgMenu class?

Comment: Please post all your code and let us know what you have tried.

Comment: your ul li ids need to be classes

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have to have pure CSS? If you ever decide to change your mind, here's a pretty simple way to achieve something like that. http://jsfiddle.net/17nq5hzw/

Answer (score 1):

first change your li ids to classes, then add a a:focus class to your images and add a width.  See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjr3jmdr/2/)
e.g.

```
.jimgMenu ul li.landscapes a:focus {
background: url("http://www.yourdomain.com/images/landscape.jpg") repeat scroll 0%;
width:500px;
}
```